# Can't connect to Azure signalR in a browser

Tags: signalr, azure-signalr

When I try to connect a React client app I got 403 error
Forbidden for `https://<domain of Azure SignalR>/SignalRTestHub`
and 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable for

```
https://<IP of Azure SignalR>/SignalRTestHub.
```

But when the backend application connects then everything works fine. Whats going on with front-end ?
Code exmple:

```
Asp.net core
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapHub<SignalRTestHub>("/SignalRTestHub");
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
services.AddSignalR()
    .AddAzureSignalR("ConnectionString");
[Authorize]
public class SignalRTestHub : Hub
{ }
```

React

```
const newConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
   .withUrl(`https://<DNS of Azure SignalR>/signalrtesthub`, {
       skipNegotiation: true,
       transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets,
       accessTokenFactory: () => "token"
   })
   .configureLogging(LogLevel.Error)
   .withAutomaticReconnect()
   .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use your app servers address in your client code, like following:

```
const newConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
   .withUrl(`https://<your app server>/signalrtesthub`, {
       skipNegotiation: false,
       transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets,
       accessTokenFactory: () => "token"
   })
   .configureLogging(LogLevel.Error)
   .withAutomaticReconnect()
   .build();
```

if you want to skip negotiation:

- Let clients know the service key, then them can generate the JWT token by themselves, but its a **bad** idea for security.
- Clients request another API to fetch the JWT token from your app server.

  ```
  const newConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
     .withUrl(`https://<DNS of Azure SignalR>/client?hubs=signalrtesthub`, {
         skipNegotiation: true,
         transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets,
         accessTokenFactory: () => "<token>"
     })
     .configureLogging(LogLevel.Error)
     .withAutomaticReconnect()
     .build();
  ```